# How to fix irregular behavior of string value given by setup method of mapper in mapreduce?

Tags: string, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm very new to MapReduce and was learning about the implementation of the setup method. The new string value given by configuration is printing correctly but when I tried to further process it, the initial value of the string comes in action. I know the string is immutable, but it should provide the value currently pointing to, to other methods.

```
public class EMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    String wordstring = "abcd"; //initialized wordstring with "abcd"


    public void setup(Context context) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration(context.getConfiguration());
        wordstring = config.get("mapper.word"); // As string is immutable,
        // wordstring should now point to
        // value given by mapper.word
        //Here mapper.word="ankit" by 
        //using -D in hadoop command

    }

    String def = wordstring;
    String jkl = String.valueOf(wordstring); //tried to copy current value 
    //but 
    //string jkl prints the initial 
    /value.

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
    throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        context.write(new Text("wordstring=" + wordstring + "   " + "def=" + 
                def),
            new Text("jkl=" + jkl));
    }
}


public class EDriver extends Configured implements Tool {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EDriver.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Driver started");

        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new EDriver(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }

    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.printf("Usage: %s  needsarguments",
                getClass().getSimpleName());
            return -1;
        }
        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = new Job(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(EDriver.class);
        job.setJobName("E Record Reader");

        job.setMapperClass(EMapper.class);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setReducerClass(EReducer.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(NullWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setInputFormatClass(ExcelInputFormat.class);

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }

}
```

I expected output to be

```
   wordstring=ankit   def=ankit   jkl=ankit
```

Actual output is

```
   wordstring=ankit   def=abcd    jkl=abcd
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the mutability of Strings, and everything to do with code execution order.

Your `setup` method will only be called *after* any class-level commands are executed. The order you write the code doesn't change anything. If you were to re-write the top section of your code in the order that it actually executes, you'd have:

```
public class EMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    String wordstring = "abcd";
    String jkl = String.valueOf(wordstring);

    public void setup(Context context) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration(context.getConfiguration());
        wordstring = config.get("mapper.word"); //By the time this is called, jkl has already been assigned to "abcd"
    }
```

So it's not surprising that `jkl` is still `abcd`. You should set `jkl` within the `setup` method, like so:

```
public class EMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    String wordstring;
    String jkl;

    public void setup(Context context) {
        Configuration config = new Configuration(context.getConfiguration());
        wordstring = config.get("mapper.word");
        jkl = wordstring;
        //Here, jkl and wordstring are both different variables pointing to "ankit"
    }

    //Here, jkl and wordstring are null, as setup(Context context) has not yet run

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
        throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        //Here, jkl and wordstring are both different variables pointing to "ankit"
        context.write(new Text("wordstring=" + wordstring),
            new Text("jkl=" + jkl));
    }
```

Of course you don't actually need `jkl`, you can just directly use `wordstring`.

Comment: I read somewhere, the problem is due to difference in location of objects i.e. string constant pool & string heap area. . I cannot use wordstring given by "mapper.word " because its object is in string heap area I think.But applying intern() method too didn't work

Comment: You're really overthinking this. It's much simpler than that. Have you tried implementing my answer?

Comment: I implemented it but then I tried to apply some string methods like split, toCharArray etc. on jkl (the one you told to write inside setup method) and all of them gave nullpointerexception

Comment: Did you do them inside the `setup` or `map` methods? Anywhere else and you will see NPEs. Might I suggest you experiment with variable scoping outside of the MapReduce framework? This will give you an understanding of variable initialisation and scoping. Then you can work on your MapReduce job.

Comment: Is there no solution? I need it .

Comment: I have given you the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the help.I will join some classes. But I really need those string methods to work on jkl outside the setup method. Thankyou

Comment: That's not possible, nor is there a reason for you to need to do that. If you need to do something for all map records once per mapper, do it in `setup`. If you need to do something for each individual input record, do it in `map`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. Actually, I was running Hadoop in the distributed mode where SETUP, MAPPER, REDUCER, and CLEANUP  run on different JVMs. So, data cannot be transported from SETUP to MAPPER directly. The first wordstring object was initialized to "abcd" in mapper. I tried to change the wordstring in SETUP(another object of wordstring was created) which was actually taking place in another JVM.
So, when I tried to copy the "wordstring" in jkl at

String jkl = String.valueOf(wordstring);

the first value of wordstring(the one created by mapper &initialized to "abcd") was being copied to jkl.

If I run Hadoop in standalone mode, it will use a single JVM and the value given to wordstring by SETUP would have been copied to jkl.

Thus, jkl got the copy of wordstring initialized to "abcd" and not the one given by SETUP.

I used

HashMap map=new HashMap();

to transport data between SETUP to MAPPER, and then jkl got a copy of value given by wordstring of SETUP.